# PHP how to do math in foreach cycle

Tags: php

I have a dynamical fields that contains values and i need to do math with them. What is the way to do it in `foreach`, do i have to save each value at the end of each loop?

Example there is 4 fields:

```
 - $Field1 = 2;
 - $Field2 = 2;
 - $Field3 = 2;
 - $Field4 = 2; 

 Example math formula:
$sum = $Field1 * $Field2 + $Field3 - $Field4 ;
```

What i have is that I print these dynamical values into table and the table adapts users inputs:

```
<tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_POST['fields'] as $key => $value) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $value['description']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['hour_rate']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['hours']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['fixed_cost']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['discount']; ?></td>
                <td?<?php echo $SUM ?> </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
```

I can get **TOTAL SUM** (in this case $SUM in table)  of all these values, but not 1 by 1.

```
    $kopa+= number_format($value['hours'], 2)* number_format($value['hour_rate'], 2) + number_format($value['fixed_cost'], 2) - number_format($value['discount'], 2);
```

How can i get total value of each loop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, but use formula you have (for `$kopa`), but with normal assignment `$sum = ...`. Then `$kopa += $sum`. Also use `number_format()` for display only - not in calculations.

Comment: @shudder Well for example loop will go around 5 times. I need to get these values $SUM at each loop so i can print it out. I need to get out sum for these fields at each loop  ``<td><?php echo $value['hour_rate']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['hours']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['fixed_cost']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['discount']; ?></td> `` Please let me know if something is still not clear.

Comment: Have you tried to just calculate that sum in loop (`$kopa += $SUM`) and display it after loop is finished?

Comment: @shudder Your method works as well! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function with your formular and a extra foreach. Use the function inside your foreach loop. You can even loop over the fields in the array. (If you get them as array.)

```
function doMath ($array){
     $sum = $array['field1'] * $array['field2'] + $..
     return $sum;
}

foreach ($whatever as $key => $value) {
    echo doMath ($array ['withFields']);  
}
```